# $f(f^{-1}(V))\subset V$ on the proof $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(X,\tau_x)\to(Y,\tau_Y)$ be a continuous function and let $A\subset X$. Therefore $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$

Given $x\in \bar{A}$ and $y\in f(\bar{A})$. Let $V$ be an open set of $Y$ so that $y\in V$. As $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}(V)$ is open of $X$. So $f^{-1}(V)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap f(A)\supset f(f^{-1}(V))\cap f(A)=f(f^{-1}(V)\cap f(A))\neq\emptyset$. This shows $f(\bar{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$

I have been striving to understand this proof but I cannot picture it.

**Questions:**

How can $V\cap f(A)\supset f(f^{-1}(V))\cap f(A)$ be true? I cannot understand $f(f^{-1}(V))\subset V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see $f(f^{-1}(V)) \subset V$, let $x \in f^{-1}(V)$.  Then by definition, $f(x) \in V$.  In other words, for all $x \in f^{-1}(V), f(x) \in V$.  This means that $$\{f(x) : x \in f^{-1}(V)\} =: f(f^{-1}(V)) \subset V$$
where the equality is the definition of $f(f^{-1}(V))$.

Comment: How can I visualize this inequality? Can you provide me an example with a function? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @PedroGomes - why don't you choose some functions and sets $V$ yourself, and see what happens. This holds for any functions and sets.  Marcus's explanation is correct and can hardly be explained more clearly.

Comment: I have done that and unsuccefully that property did not hold. When I choose an interval of a function what happens is that $f(f^{-1}(V))=V$.

Comment: @PedroGomes, the symbol $\subset$ doesn't necessarily mean "strict subset." Your example works, then.